# How to maintain the order of a nested dictionary in python (not plain, but nested)?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, python-2.x, ordereddictionary

I just copied a dictionary generated from another program to python program(hardcoded in python code).

```
a = {'b':{'d':3, 'c':4}, 'a':2}
```

but while reading the dictionary, the order is getting changed which is creating problem.

If I use OrderedDict also, only the top level order is getting saved but not of the inner dictionary.

I need the order as I am generating a tree based on the dictionary data, so that when I read back from that tree, I will get the same order. I am using python 2 version.

Thanks. Is this the drawback from python?

**Edit:** I am using this single line statement:

```
a = OrderedDict({'b':{'d':3, 'c':4}, 'a':2})
```

I just gave the simple dictionary as example but my actual dictionary is very big, so I cannot manually add OrderedDict to all inner dictionaries to make it ordered. Looking for solution in python 2, if not possible, please provide in python 3

Comment: Post the code you used for the OrderedDict, You probably just forgot to make the nested dict an OrderedDict as well.

Comment: I am using this single line statement: a = OrderedDict({'b':{'d':3, 'c':4}, 'a':2})

Answer (score 1):

Your inner dictionary should also be an OrderedDict.

You could alternatively use an associative list (a list of key-value pairs).
I think this is closer to what you're trying to do: respecting the exact order or what you read.

Another alternative is to maintain a list (for the order) and a dict to access elements. This must be done at every level.

Comment: How do I make the inner to be ordered, reading itself is creating issue

Comment: How do you read it ? Parsing with your code ? You should use an OrderedDict or a List if possible.

Answer (score 0):

#### Dictionaries are not ordered in Python 2.x

So *any* solution which reads in your data as a regular dictionary will be useless to you. You need to focus on this aspect of your workflow first, for which you have provided no information or code.

#### Use lists of tuples with `OrderedDict`

This is the **incorrect** way to initialise an `OrderedDict`:

```
a = OrderedDict({'b': {'d':3, 'c':4}, 'a':2})
```

This fails specifically because the dictionary you feed is unordered in Python 2.x. In addition, you haven't attempted to make the *inner* dictionary an `OrderedDict`.

You need, instead, to feed *lists of tuples*, which are ordered, to both the outer `OrderedDict` *and* inner `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = OrderedDict([('b', OrderedDict([('b', 3), ('c', 4)])), ('a', 2)])
```

Comment: Thank you. But the dictionary (tree node strcuture) which is copied from another java file is of too big, I cannot change all sub dictionaries manually. Could you let me know if this is directly possible in python 3 (if not in 2), so that I can use python 3 for my standalone script.

Comment: @KalyanKumar, Sorry, I don't understand your question. As stated, your problem is understanding why `OrderedDict({'b':{'d':3, 'c':4}, 'a':2})` doesn't preserve ordering as you expect. If you need something else, kindly [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53025074/edit) to make it clearer.